# keeping the menu attached to the sidebar

Tags: html, css, vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

I'm trying to create a hovering menu which you would show up when you click on the text on the sidebar. I have used `position:absolute` so that I can position it at the end of the sidebar. However, if I resize the window, the submenu is not attached to the sidebar. I want that the submenu is always attached to the sidebar. I'm using bootstrap vue for the grid system. How do I achieve this?

[Codesandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/ancient-cache-owdxp?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue)

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="hello" @click="hoverMenu">click me</div>
    <div v-if="showMenu" class="submenu">
      <div>One</div>
      <div>two</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    msg: String,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      showMenu: false,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    hoverMenu() {
      this.showMenu = !this.showMenu;
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.hello {
  background: lightblue;
  height: 100vh;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.submenu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  display: block;
  background: yellow;
  left: 156px;
}
</style>
```

app.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <b-row>
      <b-col md="2">
        <HelloWorld />
      </b-col>
      <b-col md="10"> hello </b-col>
    </b-row>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import HelloWorld from "./components/HelloWorld";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    HelloWorld,
  },
};
</script>

<style>
#app {
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
}
</style>
```

Comment: When you say "end of the sidebar", what exactly do you mean? Top right corner? Right beneath the text? It's not clear

Comment: like right next to the blue sidebar after the sidebar ends in the horizontal axis. if you see my codesandbox, I hardcoded `left: 156px` to do that but bootstrap is responsive and `md="2"` keeps changing as we resize the view so it doesn't stay in place with `left: `156px`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I got it correctly, but in order to do what you want you need a relative parent to your absolute sidebar

```
<div class="sidebar-wrapper">
    <div class="hello" @click="hoverMenu">click me</div>
    <div v-if="showMenu" class="submenu">
      <div>One</div>
      <div>two</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

```
.sidebar-wrapper {
    position: relative;
}
```

And now you can style the `submenu` w.r.t. `sidebar-wrapper`:

```
.submenu { 
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px; 
    background: yellow;
    width: 90px;
    right: 0; // set starting point to the right
    transform: translateX(100%); // move it more to the right with 100% of it's width

}
```

Comment: it kind of works but what if I don't have a fixed width for the submenu?

Comment: @deadbeforesunlight if you know the width of the sidebar to be `156px` you can do `left: 156px` and don't use `right`. And set the `width: 156px` to the `hello` element

Comment: I dont know the width of the sidebar. If I knew, then this question wouldn't even arise. The width of  the sidebar is changing according to the viewport which is the problem.

Comment: @deadbeforesunlight gotcha. You didn't mention this in the question. I'll update my answer. You basically have to use `transform: translateX(100%)` to move it w.r.t it's width